# Java: Why Absolute path missing 'src' folder

Tags: java, file, directory, absolute-path

I'm passing relative path of My.class and when looking for 'dir.getAbsolutePath', it omits **'src'** folder

```
String absuliteClassPath = "com/test/My.class"
File dir = new File(cls.substring(0, cls.lastIndexOf("/")));
System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath())
```

It prints

`/Users/swapnil.kotwal/Swapnil/myproject/com/test`

But is should print

`/Users/swapnil.kotwal/Swapnil/myproject/`**src**`/com/test`

Any Idea why ?

Comment: Because the directory you're in at runtime is not the one you think. You are probably using some IDE, isn't it ?

Comment: not actually, I'm driving my class from external ant build.xml

Comment: Whatever, you are probably executing in another directory than the sources.

Comment: hmm, probably the ant copying my 'classes' into 'my project/build' directory

Comment: Whatever you’re trying to do, you’re doing it wrong.  Look into the [Class.getResource method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).